# How to reach indexpath.row of a tableview from extended collectionview?

Tags: swift, firebase

below question was added by Junaid in 2017 and I have the exact same problem that I could not sort out for 3 days.

I am working on a survey type of app where I have a question, question type, sender etc to be displayed on tableViw cell and inside I have a horizontal collectionView which will display the options from the same node on Firebase.

The number of options vary based on the question.

I believe if you check the code below and see commented out lines, you probably easily solve it but I cannot manage it :(

The question from another user posted on 2017.
"I'm trying to get the indexPath of a tableView cell in the cell class.

I've got a collectionView inside the table view cells and I'm trying to make label inside the collectionView cell show the indexPath.row of the tableView cell that particular collectionView in."

I tried to get the indexpath.row of the tableView cell and implement it under collectionView itemAtRow function but it does not work.

```
class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var surveyArray : [SurveyClass] = [SurveyClass]()
var ref: DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle : DatabaseHandle?
let tableViewCellIdentifier = "HomeTableCell"
let collectionViewCellIdentifier = "HomeCollectionViewCell"
let tableViewHeaderNibName = "HomeTableViewHeaderView"
let tableViewHeaderIdentifier = "HomeTableViewHeader"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let headerNib = UINib(nibName: tableViewHeaderNibName, bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(headerNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: tableViewHeaderIdentifier)
    retrieveSurveys()
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return surveyArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCellIdentifier) as! HomeTableViewCell
    cell.questionTextView.text = surveyArray[indexPath.row].question
    cell.typeLabel.text = surveyArray[indexPath.row].type
    cell.countLabel.text = surveyArray[indexPath.row].count
    cell.senderLabel.text = surveyArray[indexPath.row].sender
    cell.tableIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath
    return cell
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func configureTableView (){
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 316.0
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 45.0
    tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 8.0
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 45
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 8
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: tableViewHeaderIdentifier) as! HomeTableViewHeaderView

    headerView.categoryLabel.text = "democrappy v1"
    headerView.typeLabel.text = "Test"
    return headerView
}

// MARK: - Retrieve Messages

func retrieveSurveys() {
    let surveysDB = Database.database().reference().child("surveys")
    surveysDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
        let question = snapshotValue["question"]!
        let type = snapshotValue["type"]!
        let count = snapshotValue["count"]!
        let filled = snapshotValue["filled"]!
        let sender = snapshotValue["sender"]!
        let option1 = snapshotValue["option1"]!
        let option2 = snapshotValue["option2"]!
        let noOfOptions = snapshotValue["noOfOptions"]!
        let surveyRetrieved = SurveyClass()
        surveyRetrieved.question = question
        surveyRetrieved.type = type
        surveyRetrieved.count = count
        surveyRetrieved.filled = filled
        surveyRetrieved.sender = sender
        surveyRetrieved.option1 = option1
        surveyRetrieved.option2 = option2
        surveyRetrieved.noOfOptions = noOfOptions
        self.surveyArray.append(surveyRetrieved)
        print(self.surveyArray)
        self.configureTableView()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

extension HomeTableViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    print("Gokce \(indexPath.item)")

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
    // Doesnt work! Int((surveyArray[indexPath.row].noOfOptions)!) ?? 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
    cell.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.tableIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath
    // doesnt work cell.optionLabel.text = [surveyArray[indexPath.row].option1, surveyArray[indexPath.row].option2][indexPath.item]
    return cell
    }
}
```

import UIKit

class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
var tableIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

@IBOutlet weak var indexRowLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var questionTextView: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var typeLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var senderLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

}

Comment: Show your ```HomeTableViewCell``` as well. There you have ```tableIndexPath``` (no need to cast it into ```NSIndexPath```). Just pass ```tableIndexPath.row``` to the collectionView cells.

Comment: Thank you Starsky for the help. Below I share the HomeTableViewCell

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you're doing. You have a UITableViewController, you have the datasource for it, but then you have an extension for the same UITableViewController where you handle the CollectionView datasource, but you don't have a collectionView declared here. I asked you to show me the code in ```HomeTableViewCell```. This is the cell that you're dequeuing in your tableView. Inside that cell I was expecting a collectionView, but not in the same UITableViewController.
P.S.: In ```retrieveSurveys``` you need to parse your json and map it into objects of type ```Survey```.

Comment: Hi again Starsky. I edited the code and at the bottom you have the HomeTableViewCell. What I try to do is to have the collectionView to be a part of tableview and display some information that i append to SurveyArray under retrieveSurveys. It may be an easy fix. The problem is I am not very capable yet.

Comment: First of all, you don't need to cast to NSIndexPath. Use ```IndexPath```. Secondly, if that's all you have inside your ```HomeTableViewCell```, then it is not correct. You need to implement the CollectionViewDataSource inside that cell. Move all your code from the extension to the HomeTableViewCell: ```extension HomeTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate { }```

Comment: Thank you so much for your concern Starsky. But now my collectionView does not appear when I run the app. In addition, I cannot reach the surveyArray to pull out the options to display :(

Comment: The code is pretty unclear. Just so we're on the same page, the Firebase observe function will iterate over each child node, one at a time and create a new SurveyClass() populated with firebase data. Then you're refreshing the tableView with every child (which will cause flicker) but your also calling `self.configureTableView()` for each child as well. It's unclear why that's being done.

Comment: and this `// Doesnt work! Int((surveyArray[indexPath.row].noOfOptions)!) ?? 1` won't work because there is no `indexPath.row` in the `numberOfItemsInSection` function.

Answer (score 0):

The `HomeTableViewCell` has a property `tableIndexPath`. This property has stored the information that you want which is the `tableViewCell` indexPath.

So inside the `HomeTableViewCell` where you assign the `tableIndexPath` to each cell of the collection view you have to pass the `tableIndexPath` value of `HomeTableViewCell`.

Your mistake is the `cell.tableIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath` where you pass inside the collectionView cell the indexPath of the collection view delegate function.

Comment: Dear Βασίλης Δ., thank you so much. Sorry to ask you again but what do i need to do to pass the tableIndexPath to collectionView?

Comment: instead of cell.tableIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath, you should write cell.tableIndexPath = self. tableViewCell, because you have already passed the indexpath cell position to the cell so you just need to pass from that cell the position to the collection view cell

Comment: Thnk you Βασίλης Δ.   cell.tableIndexPath = self. tableViewCell gives me the error "Value of type 'HomeTableViewController' has no member 'tableViewCell'  though.

Comment: Yes self shouldn't be the HomeTableViewController object but the HomeTableViewCell object. You said "I've got a collectionView inside the table view cells " so the file that you create the HomeCollectionViewCell object should be inside the HomeTableViewCell class. And the delegate of the HomeCollectionViewCell should be the HomeTableViewCell class not the HomeTableViewController.